# How to find lines that do not match pattern in a multiline block?

Tags: python, regex, multiline, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a way to determine if a multiline block of text contains any line not matching a format `text- more text`.

So given this text:

```
hello- 12345
hello bye
bye- 123
```

It should match `hello bye`.

If I try to match those lines that do match this pattern I get the lines 1 and 3:

```
import re

text = """hello- 12345
hello bye
bye- 123"""

for m in re.finditer(r"^\w+-\s+[^\n]+$", text, re.MULTILINE):
    print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
```

That is, it returns:

```
00-12: hello- 12345
23-31: bye- 123
```

However, using a negative lookahead on this condition does not match anything. That is, the following returns an empty list `[]` instead of `['hello bye']`:

```
print re.findall(r"^(?!\w+-\s+[^\n]+)$", text, re.MULTILINE)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negative lookahead needs to have ending anchor `$` and outside the lookahead you should have matching pattern before `$`:

```
print re.findall(r"^(?!\w+-\s+[^\n]+$).+$", text, re.MULTILINE)
['hello bye']
```

Or little simplified:

```
print re.findall(r"^(?!\w+-\s+.+$).+", text, re.MULTILINE)
['hello bye']
```

`^(?!\w+-\s+[^\n]+)$` will only match an **empty line** as it will match end anchor `$` after start anchor `^` (middle section being lookahead).

Comment: Beautiful! It works : ) I am not sure if I fully understand it: the ending anchor `$` must be inside the lookahead but then, also, outside the lookahead I must include some kind of pattern because otherwise it will not match anything?

Comment: In this one `r"^(?!\w+-\s+.+$).+"` we are not repeating end anchor. But when you have `^(?!\w+-\s+[^\n]+)$` it means after start assert that string on RHS doesn't match `\w+-\s+[^\n]+` pattern. Remember lookahead is just assertion so internal pointer is still at start and then you're matching `$` so essentially you regex will only match `^$`

Comment: I will do some little tests to fully understand it. As always, many many thanks! Accepted and mentally upvoted again : )